# Fixing table join on SQL Query results in query not running

Tags: sql, inner-join, teradata

I am working in Teradata on a legacy SQL query used to make a temp table that pushes data to a downstream data analytics application. I am new to the job, and after taking a quick look at the table, I noticed an error where the query was referencing the same table within the join conditions. After fixing it, I re-ran the query, expecting better results.

The database holds a couple billion records. Before fixing the query, the original temp table contained around 2.5 million rows, and took about 5 seconds to run. After fixing the query, the query will run for hours with no signs of progress, then usually crashes the application.

The original query is below. I put a comment in where I 'fixed' the join.

I ran just the select statement, and used `sample 10` just to see if I can pull any data back, but again, it's taking forever to run.

Any thoughts on why the query isn't executing? Or how to improve performance to see if it's actually working? Or even how to check if anything is happening under the hood?

```
create multiset volatile table order_date as
(
SELECT a.ord_nbr,
a.ord_spot_cnt AS ord_spot_cnt,
a.ord_totl_amt AS ord_totl_amt,
a.eclipse_regn_nm AS eclipse_regn_nm,
a.sale_offc_key AS sales_office,
so.sale_offc_nm AS sales_office_name,
a.sale_prsn_key AS sales_person,
sp.sale_prsn_nm AS sales_person_name,
trunc(a.ctrc_begn_dt, 'month') ctrc_mnth,
(cast(a.ctrc_end_dt AS date format 'yyyy/mm/dd') - cast(a.ctrc_begn_dt AS date format 'yyyy/mm/dd')) AS ctrc_duration,
CASE WHEN extract (month FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) in (10,11) THEN 1
WHEN extract (month FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) in (12) AND extract (day FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) <= 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS first_look_flg,
CASE WHEN extract (month FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) in (12) AND extract (day FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) > 22 THEN 2
WHEN extract (month FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) in (1) THEN 2
WHEN extract (month FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) in (2) AND extract (day FROM a.ctrc_begn_dt) <= 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS second_look_flg
FROM PRD_AM_BI_1.am_order_eda_fact a
inner join prd_am_bi_1.AM_SALES_OFFICE_EDA_DIM so
on (a.SALE_OFFC_KEY = so.SALE_OFFC_KEY
and so.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM = so.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM)
-- I 'fixed' the above line to "and a.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM = so.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM)"
inner join prd_am_bi_1.AM_SALES_PERSON_EDA_DIM sp
on (a.SALE_PRSN_KEY = sp.SALE_PRSN_KEY
and a.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM = sp.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM)
)
with data
on commit preserve rows
;
```

EDIT:

Here is the EXPLAIN output for the 'fixed query. Both queries have the same total estimated time, so I'm not sure why the 'fixed' one is not actually executing.

```
Explanation                                                              
 ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
   1) First, we lock PRD_AM_1.AM_ORDER_EDA_FACT in view                  
      PRD_AM_BI_1.am_order_eda_fact in TD_MAP1 for access, we lock       
      PRD_AM_1.AM_SALES_PERSON_EDA_DIM in view                           
      PRD_AM_BI_1.AM_SALES_PERSON_EDA_DIM in TD_MAP1 for access, and we  
      lock PRD_AM_1.AM_SALES_OFFICE_EDA_DIM in view                      
      PRD_AM_BI_1.AM_SALES_OFFICE_EDA_DIM in TD_MAP1 for access.         
   2) Next, we execute the following steps in parallel.                  
        1) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_MAP1 from               
           PRD_AM_1.AM_SALES_OFFICE_EDA_DIM in view                      
           PRD_AM_BI_1.AM_SALES_OFFICE_EDA_DIM by way of an all-rows     
           scan with no residual conditions into Spool 2 (all_amps),     
           which is redistributed by hash code to all AMPs to all AMPs   
           in TD_Map1.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 2 by row hash.  
           The size of Spool 2 is estimated with high confidence to be   
           426 rows (21,300 bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 
           0.01 seconds.                                                 
        2) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_MAP1 from               
           PRD_AM_1.AM_SALES_PERSON_EDA_DIM in view                      
           PRD_AM_BI_1.AM_SALES_PERSON_EDA_DIM by way of an all-rows     
           scan with no residual conditions into Spool 3 (all_amps),     
           which is redistributed by hash code to all AMPs to all AMPs   
           in TD_Map1.  Then we do a SORT to order Spool 3 by row hash.  
           The size of Spool 3 is estimated with high confidence to be   
           229,155 rows (10,770,285 bytes).  The estimated time for this 
           step is 0.04 seconds.                                         
        3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step in TD_MAP1 from               
           PRD_AM_1.AM_ORDER_EDA_FACT in view                            
           PRD_AM_BI_1.am_order_eda_fact by way of an all-rows scan with 
           no residual conditions into Spool 4 (all_amps), which is      
           redistributed by hash code to all AMPs to all AMPs in TD_Map1.
           Then we do a SORT to order Spool 4 by row hash.  The size of  
           Spool 4 is estimated with high confidence to be 2,041,151     
           rows (136,757,117 bytes).  The estimated time for this step   
           is 0.21 seconds.                                              
   3) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_Map1 from Spool 2 (Last Use) by  
      way of a RowHash match scan, which is joined to Spool 3 (Last Use) 
      by way of a RowHash match scan.  Spool 2 and Spool 3 are joined    
      using a merge join, with a join condition of ("ECLIPSE_REGN_NM =   
      ECLIPSE_REGN_NM").  The result goes into Spool 5 (all_amps), which 
      is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 5 is estimated    
      with no confidence to be 203,927 rows (17,129,868 bytes).  The     
      estimated time for this step is 0.02 seconds.                      
   4) We do an all-AMPs JOIN step in TD_Map1 from Spool 4 (Last Use) by  
      way of a RowHash match scan, which is joined to Spool 5 (Last Use) 
      by way of a RowHash match scan.  Spool 4 and Spool 5 are joined    
      using a merge join, with a join condition of ("(ECLIPSE_REGN_NM =  
      ECLIPSE_REGN_NM) AND ((SALE_PRSN_KEY = SALE_PRSN_KEY) AND          
      ((ECLIPSE_REGN_NM = ECLIPSE_REGN_NM) AND (SALE_OFFC_KEY =          
      SALE_OFFC_KEY )))").  The result goes into Spool 1 (group_amps),   
      which is built locally on the AMPs.  The size of Spool 1 is        
      estimated with no confidence to be 2,041,151 rows (293,925,744     
      bytes).  The estimated time for this step is 0.02 seconds.         
   -> The contents of Spool 1 are sent back to the user as the result of 
      statement 1.  The total estimated time is 0.24 seconds.
```

Comment: Can you share (sanitized) EXPLAIN and/or Primary Indexes? Was the result returned by the "wrong" query correct? Is `ECLIPSE_REGN_NM` part of the Primary Key or the partitioning?

Comment: Have you collected stats on the column you added to the join?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. (Constraints, indexes & plans are critical to performance.)

Comment: The "unfixed" query probably did different joins. The "fixed" query optimizes to a so-called *star join*, but the number of rows in *step 3* is probably heavily underestimated (how many different values exist in `ECLIPSE_REGN_NM`?). Collecting Statistics on those columns should fix it (you might not have appropriate rights). Based on the names of the columns (`...KEY`) `ECLIPSE_REGN_NM` can probably be removed from both join (the original `so.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM = so.ECLIPSE_REGN_NM` was equivalent to `1=1`). What's the Primary Index of those dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

Review the explain plan to see where the query is spending the most cost.  Then focus on reducing that cost by using different join, filter, subquery, or making use of an index.